# Use canvas context works as global but not when I pass it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web, html5-canvas

I'm working on a final project (interactive Javascript game, etc.) and decided to give myself a challenge by learning canvas and HTML5. I'm also trying to learn Javascript objects (and organize what so many people seem to throw into one big script tag), etc. so excuse some possible stupidity on my part. :)

So currently I have the core working but I'm trying to make a start screen (I'm going to blur a paused random game behind the start options). The game involves dodging obstacles. When I draw the obstacles using a global variable context everything works. When I try to pass in a variable it dies. Here's what works:

```
var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("objectsToAvoidCanvas");
var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

function Obstacle(){
    var height;
    var width;
    var xPosition;
    var yPosition;
    var isOffScreen;
    var isSafeToAddMore;
    var speed;
    var anonymousCreation = function(){
        this.width = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);
        this.height = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerHeight * 0.7) + 1);       

        this.xPosition = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);
        this.yPosition = this.height * -1;

        this.isOffScreen = false;
        this.isSafeToAddMore = false;

        this.speed = 1;

        mainContext.fillStyle = '#009933';
        mainContext.fillRect(this.xPosition, this.yPosition, this.width, this.height);

    };  

    anonymousCreation();

};

Obstacle.prototype.drawInRandomPlace = function(){
    yPosition = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);

    mainContext.fillStyle = '#009933';
    mainContext.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);        
};
```

However, something along these lines breaks:

```
    function Obstacle(context){
        var height;
        var width;
        var xPosition;
        var yPosition;
        var isOffScreen;
        var isSafeToAddMore;
        var speed;
        var mainCanvas
        var mainContext

var anonymousCreation = function(){
            this.mainContext = context

            this.width = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);
            this.height = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerHeight * 0.7) + 1);       

            this.xPosition = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);
            this.yPosition = this.height * -1;

            this.isOffScreen = false;
            this.isSafeToAddMore = false;

            this.speed = 1;

            mainContext.fillStyle = '#009933';
            mainContext.fillRect(this.xPosition, this.yPosition, this.width, this.height);

        };  

        anonymousCreation();

    };


    Obstacle.prototype.drawInRandomPlace = function(){
        yPosition = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);

        mainContext.fillStyle = '#009933';
        mainContext.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
    };
```

I've tried using `this.mainContext = context` or actually grabbing from a passed string `document.getElementById(aString)`. Just a bunch of different variations, etc inside the constructor. Been working on this for over an hour and can't figure it out so I thought I'd ask you guys. Probably been staring at it for too long.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you expand upon "it dies"? Is there an error being thrown? What does the developer console say?

Comment: It doesn't display any rectangles that I draw. Apparently I have 500 some errors. Nothing is directly attributed to any of my dev files... "fill style of undefined url"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switched to `this.mainContext`, you didn't replace all other instances of `mainContext`:

```
 var anonymousCreation = function(){
                this.mainContext = context;

                this.width = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);
                this.height = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerHeight * 0.7) + 1);       

                this.xPosition = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 0.8) + 1);
                this.yPosition = this.height * -1;

                this.isOffScreen = false;
                this.isSafeToAddMore = false;

                this.speed = 1;

                /* old
                mainContext.fillStyle = '#009933';
                mainContext.fillRect(this.xPosition, this.yPosition, this.width, this.height);
                */

                this.mainContext.fillStyle = '#009933'; //added this.
                this.mainContext.fillRect(this.xPosition, this.yPosition, this.width, this.height); //added this.

            };  

            anonymousCreation();

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.mainContext = context` is the guilty one. There's no context parameter to your `anonymousCreation` function. <strike>While sub-functions have access to variables declared with `var`, they can't access parameters from their parent function.</strike> I lied. I tested [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hmd180tk/1/) and it seems to work.I don't really see the point of the subfunction though, but Javascript is a very loose language and you can do things in exotic fashions.

When you use "var" to declare content inside an object, you declare private members that won't be accessible from the outside. Unless you plan on making getters and setters, I don't recommend doing that systematically. I prefer doing this:

```
function MyObject(arg1, arg2) {
    this.property1 = arg1;
    this.property2 = arg2;
}

MyObject.prototype.myFunction = function(arg) {
    console.log(this.property1 + this.property2);
};

sampleInstance = new MyObject(1, 2);
```